# How to use DebugKit toolbar in cakephp 2.1.3 or cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have tried to use cakephp Debugkit toolbar for `cakephp 2.1.3`... but it is not working fine..

I have implemented debugkit on `cakephp 1.3` it is working fine..

i downloaded debugkit for `cakephp 2.1.3`. I rechecked that..

How i am implementing it??

```
app/plugin/DebugKit   ///this is my path for debugkit
```

I checked my debug mode is 2..

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

how i am loading my debug kit in Appcontroller..'

```
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
```

It is showing error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /var/www/guest1/cakephp-2.1.3/app/Plugin/debug_kit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php on line 165
```

I download debugkit from different source but same result.

Thanks !

it is showing error in this function and line

```
public function implementedEvents() {
    $before = function ($name) {
        return function () use ($name) {
            DebugTimer::start($name, __d('debug_kit', $name));
        };
    };
    $after = function ($name) {
        return function () use ($name) {
            DebugTimer::stop($name);
        };
    };
```

I loaded file in bootstrap.php at the end

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

Error:-

```
    Error: DebugKit.ToolbarComponent could not be found.

Error: Create the class ToolbarComponent below in file: /var/www/guest1/cakephp-2.1.3/app/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php
```

Comment: could you show us what line 165 in `ToolbarComponent.php` looks likE?

Comment: @SiGanteng See i updated my error with line no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. DebugKit worked on my local server, but crashed with the same error online. The problem was that i didn't have a database connection. After i succesfully connected to the database, debugkit worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

You have downloaded the latest version of the DebugKit plugin, which uses [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). As you can see there, you need at least PHP 5.3 for this to work.

Simply download an earlier version of DebugKit which is compatible with your version of PHP.

Comment: I tried that but.. it is showing error, Error: DebugKit.ToolbarComponent could not be found. and Error: Create the class ToolbarComponent below in file: /var/www/guest1/cakephp-2.1.3/app/Plugin/debug_kit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php ..

Comment: @Learner: The folder name for the plugin should be `DebugKit`, not `debug_kit`, this was changed in cake 2 as well.

Comment: @Learner: Just to make sure.. 1) Did you load the plugin in bootstrap? 2) Are you sure the file exists? What happens if you try to open the file path in an editor? 3) Can you post the new error message and the location of your file?

Comment: @Learner: Are you getting the file content if you type `cat /var/www/guest1/cakephp-2.1.3/app/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php` in a terminal? If yes, you might want to check file/folder permissions, maybe your server user cannot access the newly deployed plugin? Are you getting anything in your php/cakephp/apache logs?

Comment: I checked.. that files is present.. I run that command in terminal.I gave 777 permission for that .. but this error:---Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /var/www/guest1/cakephp-2.1.3/app/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php on line 165

Comment: @Learner: So this is a new error? You didn't download an older version of the plugin?

Comment: I downloaded, for that it is showing Error: DebugKit.ToolbarComponent could not be found..

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. I guess if you are using Cakphp 2.0 and higher, you cannot use Debugkit version lower than 2 because it has a different Plugin name convention. Files have a different tree structure.

So all you have to do is use a lower version and rename the files or update PHP or use lower version of Cakephp.